# I need to find a way to scale my grid to fit the proper screen size of a device in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, gridview

I need it to look like this, but I'm having two main issues. I'm having trouble having the grid fit the size of the screen and for the Icon and Title to be on the same line as shown in the following image and for the subtitle text to be centered under the title, not the icon. I am new to Flutter app development so please excuse any ugly code. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toJIz.png)

```html
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

import '../app.dart';
import '../splash-screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AboutUs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AboutUsState createState() => _AboutUsState();
}

class _AboutUsState extends State<AboutUs> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: Container(
            child: GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 1,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                children: List.generate(
                    options.length,
                    (index) => GridOptions(
                          layout: options[index],
                        ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
  }
}

class GridLayout {
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;
  static const String _title =
      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor';
  GridLayout({this.icon, this.title, this.text});
}

List<GridLayout> options = [
  GridLayout(
      icon: Icons.build,
      title: ' Vision',
      text:
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor'),
  GridLayout(
      icon: Icons.campaign,
      title: ' Statement',
      text:
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor'),
  GridLayout(
      icon: Icons.description,
      title: ' Description',
      text:
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor'),
  GridLayout(
      icon: Icons.supervisor_account,
      title: ' Co-Organizers',
      text:
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor'),
  GridLayout(
      icon: Icons.emoji_people,
      title: ' Founder and Executive Director',
      text:
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor'),
  GridLayout(
      icon: Icons.psychology,
      title: ' Advisory Board',
      text:
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor'),
];

class GridOptions extends StatelessWidget {
  final GridLayout layout;
  GridOptions({this.layout});
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Wrap (
        spacing: 10,
        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Icon(
            layout.icon,
            size: 24,
          ),
          Text(layout.title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
          ),
          Text(layout.text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Colors.blueGrey,

              ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am New To flutter as well i hope this helps,

There are two possible solutions, that i know of.

1. wrap you wrap with FractionallySizedBox with property widthFactor: 0.9.
2. change your wrap to Column/row or Gridview set them in container and wrap with FractionallySizedBox with property widthFactor: 0.9,

In both Case you will have to do something about Long title like ' Founder and Executive Director'.

```
//For Wrap :
class GridOptions extends StatelessWidget {
final GridLayout layout;
GridOptions({this.layout});
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: FractionallySizedBox(
  widthFactor: 0.9,
  child: Wrap(
    spacing: 10,
    alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
    runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: [
      Icon(
        layout.icon,
        size: 24,
      ),
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8,
        child: Text(
          layout.title,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 41),
        child: Text(
          layout.text,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
));
}
}


//For Column/row
class GridOptions extends StatelessWidget {
final GridLayout layout;
GridOptions({this.layout});
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: FractionallySizedBox(
    widthFactor: 0.9,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Icon(
              layout.icon,
              size: 24,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8,
              child: Text(
                layout.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 41),
          child: Text(
            layout.text,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to use **gridView**.
try the following solution.

```
Widget listItem(IconData iconData, String title, String body) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          Icon(iconData),
          SizedBox(width: 20),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  title,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text(
                  body,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

then use the listItem inside `column` and `singleChildScrollView`.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          listItem(Icons.settings, 'Title', 'body',),
          listItem(Icons.settings, 'Title', 'body',),
          listItem(Icons.settings, 'Title', 'body',),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Whenever I try to run your code it says "Missing concrete implementation of 'State.build'" in my class name

Comment: in order to render UI you need to use a `build` method. let me provide you the full code.

Answer (score 0):

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            listItem(
              Icons.settings,
              'Title',
              'body',
            ),
            listItem(
              Icons.settings,
              'Title',
              'body',
            ),
            listItem(
              Icons.settings,
              'Title',
              'body',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget listItem(IconData iconData, String title, String body) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          Icon(iconData),
          SizedBox(width: 20),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  title,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text(
                  body,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```